# Appending and Replacing String doesn't work

Tags: java, android, string, append

I am trying to replace all spaces to "" and append @email.com to a String, my input is Username and Password
I have on Click listener that when Button is clicked it should manipulate the text and save it into the database

Here is my code:

```
    musername = findViewById(R.id.username);
        memail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        mfullname = findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        mpassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        register = findViewById(R.id.register);
        txt_login = findViewById(R.id.txt_login
    public void onClick(View view) {
                pd = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
                pd.setMessage("Please wait...\nWaiting too long? Please try another nickname");
                pd.show();
                //Testiram Register Sistem
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.append(musername.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s+","")).append("@email.com");
                email = stringBuilder.toString();
                String semail=email;
                String str_username = musername.getText().toString();
                String str_fullname = musername.getText().toString();
                String str_password = mpassword.getText().toString();




                register(semail,str_username, str_fullname, str_password);

            }
        });
    }

    public void register(final String username, final String fullname,final String email, String password){
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password

)
```

Comment: What do you do with `semail` after this code? It doesn't look like you use it.

Comment: @Andy I am using it (trying) in a method to register a user but it fails probably it doesn't replace the spaces and append the email domain

Comment: Do you mean trim() method?

Comment: @JustAhead No just Register method taking all the Strings and Pushing them into Database

Comment: When I add "@email.com" in username field it works but the text must be without spaces so that means it doesnt append the "@email.com" part

Comment: @SuperGeekyDude your code is working fine. Whats the problem?

Comment: @RajatMehra I have updated my code take a look and if you spot any issues tell me, it fails to register the account I must add an email extention and remove all spaces to make it work

Comment: @SuperGeekyDude If I am right, you want output like this -> John Smith will become JohnSmith@email.com

Comment: @RajatMehra exactly like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringBuilder` code is correct but If you want to fetch text from your editText and trying to make it `Email`. So you should do it on any **event**. For example you can take a button and on its click you can make your email.

```
 createEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append(musername.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s+","")).append("@email.com");
            email = stringBuilder.toString();
            String semail=email;
            String str_username = musername.getText().toString();
            String str_fullname = musername.getText().toString();
            String str_password = mpassword.getText().toString();

            register(str_username,str_fullname, semail,str_password);
    });
```

**EDIT** Relace

```
stringBuilder.append(musername.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s+"," @email.com"));
```

with

```
stringBuilder.append(musername.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\s+","")).append("@email.com");
```

Comment: I have updated my code with more info take a look if you dont mind

Comment: @RajatMehra still the same issue I don't know what does txtView.setText(email) does It cannot resolve the symbol do I need to initiazlize or smth

Comment: @SuperGeekyDude also check your actual and formal parameters of register method..You are passing semail in username and full_username in email

Comment: @SuperGeekyDude again check my edited onClick method. It will be helpful for you.

Comment: @RajatMehra Thanks a lot I found the issue and fixed it (didn't see my parameters)

Answer (score -1):

```
    String semail=email+"@email.com";
```

add "@email.com" in this line hope it will now.

Comment: This will replace all `Space` with  @email.com.

Comment: "This will replace all Space with @email.com" I guess he wanted to replace space with email@.com.

Comment: No, he wanted output like this. John Smith will become JohnSmith@email.com

Comment: O got it. then after get final sting just add sting+"@email.com"